# How do we install Ubuntu 19.10 on a Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: raspberrypi

I am excited that Ubuntu 19.10 supports the Raspberry Pi 4, but haven't seen any download links for Ubuntu 19.10 for the Raspberry Pi family yet.

Is this still in process, or do I just download the *.iso image and write it to a USB-stick, then install it from that?

I'm eager to get my latest project finished, which will be using Ubuntu to turn a 4GB Raspberry Pi 4 into a real full-blown Linux machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you install Ubuntu on the Raspberry Pi 4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154768/can-you-install-ubuntu-on-the-raspberry-pi-4)

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi

Comment: Have the same problem with USB ports not working. Was able to gain ssh access with a ethernet cable plugged in. Have not figured out how to enable USB. This is the 64bit version, haven't tried 32bit version yet.

Comment: official bug -
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1848703 Discussed here as well-
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=254649&p=1553842

Comment: I had the same issue, no USB devices with 64 bit version. However, the 32 bit version sees USB devices (USB HDD and USB Printer) with no problem.

Answer (score 5):

Here you are.

32bit (hard-float)
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.10/release/ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz

64bit
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.10/release/ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz

I have problems with USB ports do not working, but it worked on Raspian without problems.