# Raspberry Pi 4 USB Ports are not working with Ubuntu 19.10 (64bit)

Tags: usb, raspberrypi, 19.10

The USB ports are working on Raspian but are not working on Ubuntu 19.10

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb --tree
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep usb
[    0.094588] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.094642] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.094751] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.409004] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.410720] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.429087] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.03
[    1.430796] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.432515] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.434198] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-1007-raspi2 xhci-hcd
[    1.435883] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.447247] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.03
[    1.448939] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.450605] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.452281] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-1007-raspi2 xhci-hcd
[    1.453947] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.462256] dwc_otg fe980000.usb: base=(____ptrval____)
[    1.776269] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.894400] dwc_otg fe980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.896088] dwc_otg fe980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.897805] dwc_otg fe980000.usb: irq 24, io mem 0x00000000
[    1.902965] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.03
[    1.904529] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    1.904629] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.907896] usb usb3: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.909555] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.3.0-1007-raspi2 dwc_otg_hcd
[    1.911211] usb usb3: SerialNumber: fe980000.usb
[    2.140497] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    2.404243] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.540463] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    2.784461] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    2.900328] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[    3.564237] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    3.700465] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    3.944457] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    4.208271] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    4.352501] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    4.573717] usb_phy_generic phy: phy supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.592556] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error 18
[    4.704446] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[   15.842218] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you install Ubuntu on the Raspberry Pi 4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154768/can-you-install-ubuntu-on-the-raspberry-pi-4) This answer is specific to 19.10 image: https://askubuntu.com/a/1181847/

Comment: Confirmed as an issue; filed as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi2/+bug/1848790