# Replace 18.04 DE on a Pi4

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, xfce, lxde, raspberrypi

I installed the unofficial 18.04.3 on a Pi4 B (4GB) because docker is not yet supported in 19.10 and I needed it for hassio and tried also KDE (installing the Kubuntu desktop with sudo apt-get install Kubuntu-desktop) that is my usual go-to for other devices however I'm not sure if I'm missing some package/driver or if it's just that I use it with xrdp or my MicroSD but whenever I try to use the DE even for just finding a file I can't find via terminal/SSH (the pi is not connected to a display) it feels really slow and unresponsive (the "start" button menu takes a good 3-5 seconds to load even just the outline of the window) so I wanted to replace it with something lighter without the need to reinstall everything, is there a way for me to remove the current DE and replace it with something like xfce/lxde without looking for every single package that kubuntu installed? I'm a bit of a newbie with those commands on ubuntu (especially on a RPi) so I don't really know if it's possible of it'd break everything

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you install Ubuntu on the Raspberry Pi 4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154768/can-you-install-ubuntu-on-the-raspberry-pi-4) - [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1181847/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the deps personally but `sudo apt remove kubuntu-desktop && sudo apt autoremove` in theory should remove kubuntu's stuff and all other related packages, though you might want to run `apt show kubuntu-desktop` to view what it depends on or reccomends, then run `apt list --installed | grep packagenamehere` to see a package you don't want (or do want) is there. After removing everything, you can then run `sudo apt install xfce4` or `sudo apt install ldxe`

Comment: I think it worked it removing it however after installing xubuntu/xfce if I try to use rdp it crashes after the xorg login